# Using # number sign in "each" Meteor Jade

Tags: meteor, pug

Is there any difference between this code blocks ?

`each users
   span #{username}`

and

`each users
   span {{username}}`

one thing I've found   #{} can't be used in quotes (")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#{var}` syntax should only be used in text: [reference](https://github.com/mquandalle/meteor-jade#templates)

> Inside a text node you can use both {{spacebars}} and #{jade}
>   expressions but the last one is recommended:
>
> ```
> template(name="leaderboard")
>   p Welcome #{player.name}
> ```